# Поиск нужной записи в xml

Tags: java, xml

Есть xml вида :

```
<ValCurs Date="08.06.2017" name="Foreign Currency Market">
<Valute ID="R01010">
    <NumCode>036</NumCode>
    <CharCode>AUD</CharCode>
    <Nominal>1</Nominal>
    <Name>????????????? ??????</Name>
    <Value>42,7408</Value>
</Valute>
<Valute ID="R01020A">
    <NumCode>944</NumCode>
    <CharCode>AZN</CharCode>
    <Nominal>1</Nominal>
    <Name>??????????????? ?????</Name>
    <Value>33,5614</Value>
</Valute>
<Valute ID="R01035">
    <NumCode>826</NumCode>
    <CharCode>GBP</CharCode>
    <Nominal>1</Nominal>
    <Name>???? ?????????? ???????????? ???????????</Name>
    <Value>72,9587</Value>
```

Как выделить из него допустим только

```
<Valute ID="R01035">
    <NumCode>826</NumCode>
    <CharCode>GBP</CharCode>
    <Nominal>1</Nominal>
    <Name>???? ?????????? ???????????? ???????????</Name>
    <Value>72,9587</Value>
```

И сохранить только это.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам поможет xPath

```
DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = docBuilder.parse (new File("c:\\tmp\\my.xml"));
XPathFactory xPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = xPathfactory.newXPath();    
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("/Valute[@ID='R01035']");
NodeList nl = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
Element firstElement = (Element) nl.item(0);
```

Comment: спасибо что откликнулись, после строки Element firstElement = (Element) nl.item(0); что должно следовать?

Comment: То что вы хотите сделать с объектом, например firstElement.getChild("NumCode").toString()

Comment: Хочу сохранить либо в новый документ,либо в этот же, но только данные для этой записи.  firstElement.getChild("NumCode").toString() вызывает ошибку Error:(71, 25) java: method getChildNodes in interface org.w3c.dom.Node cannot be applied to given types;
  required: no arguments
  found: java.lang.String
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length